# How to compare two variables holding datetime.strptime value in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to compare to variables that are holding `date.strptime` values. Problem is I seem to be getting `nameerror` for both the variables.

```
for line in x[25:34]:
    if '2 DATE' in line:
        pos= line.find('E')
        host= line[pos+1:17]

        #print 'James Birth Date is:', (convert_date)

for line1 in x [90:99]:
     if '2 DATE' in line1:
        pos1 = line1.find('E')
        host1= line1[pos1+1:17]

    convert_date= datetime.strptime (host,'%d %b %Y').date()
    convert_date1= datetime.strptime (host, '%d %b %Y').date()

    if (convert_date > convert_date1):
        print ' James was born before he got married'
```

what may I be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the relevant lines from `x`?

Comment: Oh and do you have this: `from datetime import datetime`

Comment: Please post the exact error message you're getting.

Comment: line 23, in <module>
    if (convert_date > convert_date1):
NameError: name 'convert_date1' is not defined
logout

Comment: this is the output when i run the first "for line in x"     8 MAR 1952

Comment: yes i do have from: datetime import datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you're having trouble with [scope](http://spartanideas.msu.edu/2014/05/12/a-beginners-guide-to-pythons-namespaces-scope-resolution-and-the-legb-rule/):

```
for line in x[25:34]:
    if '2 DATE' in line:
        pos= line.find('E')
        host= line[pos+1:17]

#here host and pos don't exist anymore
```

Define them before the loop:

```
pos = None
host = None
for line in x[25:34]:
    if '2 DATE' in line:
        pos= line.find('E')
        host= line[pos+1:17]

# pos and host do exist, and if they're not None, they have been set
```

Comment: should i defines variables convert_datetime & convert_datetime1 before each loop ?

Comment: @YawAdu-BoaheneJnr. It depends where you want to use them. As it is now, you don't. Please refer to the scope tutorial I've posted link to.

Comment: when i do it your way this is the error i getif (convert_date1 > convert_date):
NameError: name 'convert_date1' is not defined
logout

Comment: @YawAdu-BoaheneJnr. Seems you are talking about a different snippet right now. The code you have in your question won't produce this error. Please just read the tutorial, and you won't have to go through this each time.

Comment: thank you. i figured it out and code is working fine now.